# Averiguar en cloud firestore un id de un documento de una coleccion

Tags: android

¿Como puedo averiguar en cloud firestore, un id de un documento en el cual solo tengo el valor de uno de sus campo?

Gracias.

Answer (score 2):

bno ps yo hice algo creo q similar en un proyecto, lo que hice fue almacenar en un campo del documento el id de dicho documento por ejemplo:

```
String biciId4(){
return Firestore.instance.collection('usuarios').document(uid).collection('bicicletas').document('bicicleta4').documentID;
```

}

luego de llamar el id de respectivo documento lo almaceno en ese documento usando el metodo de set data.

```
await DatabaseService(uid: user.uid).updateBicicletasData4(
    biciId4(),
    'Bici 4', 
    'Referencia', 
    'color', 
    'modelo', 
    'talla', 
    'Km', 
    '',
    '',
  );
```

Y este es el metodo updateBicicletasData4 que esta en la foto anterior.

```
Future<void> updateBicicletasData4(
String id,
String marca, 
String referencia, 
String color, 
String modelo, 
String talla, 
String kilometros,  
String imagen,  
String imagenfactura,
```

) async {

```
return await usuarioCollection.document(uid).collection('bicicletas').document('bicicleta4').setData({
  'id':id,
  'marca': marca,
  'referencia': referencia,
  'color': color,
  'modelo' : modelo,
  'talla' : talla,
  'kilometros' : kilometros,
  'imagen' : imagen,
  'imagenfactura' : imagenfactura,
});
```

}

Funciono asi para mi, espero que te funcione igual.

Answer (score 1):

```
DocumentReference addedDocRef = db.collection("cities").document();
System.out.println("Added document with ID: " + addedDocRef.getId());
addedDocRef.set(data);
```

Comment: Hola Juan, bienvenido y gracias por tu colaboración, las respuestas que son solo código, son consideradas de baja calidad, te sugiero que edites la tuya, y expliques de que forma resuelve el problema planteado, así evitarás que sea cerrada y/o recibir votos negativos.